# What is opposite of docker swarm init?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

With a single host with a swarm that has been created with init, the host gets networks created etc.

There appears to be no 'docker swarm destroy' or similar that purges the system back to a state before the swarm.  I did a leave --force but that left networks.

Do you have to manually tidy up a bunch of things you don't know were created or is there an easy command to get back to a clean setup?

Thanks

Comment: What networks does it leave?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`docker swarm leave` is the only command for reverting swarm membership.
It cleans up all swarm specific artefacts that were created by `docker stack deploy`, e.g. overlay networks and secrets.

If you still got user defined networks after leaving the swarm, these were probably created by `docker-compose`. Note that this is not swarm specific, it can also happen in standalone mode.

You can get a listing of all networks that were created by `docker-compose` with

```
docker network ls --filter label=com.docker.compose.project
```

and get rid of them with

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls --filter label=com.docker.compose.project -q)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the docker instance was a manager: `docker swarm leave --force`.